# how to increase quota of subscription 7 days

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

from pubsub [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#other_limits)

> Retains unacknowledged messages in persistent storage for 7 days from
>   the moment they were published.

is there a way to keep messages in subscription longer than 7 days?

didnt find in thr [APIs & services in the Google Cloud Platform Console.](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/pubsub.googleapis.com/quotas?_ga=2.67419988.-431104210.1517848587)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to persist messages in Google Cloud Pub/Sub for more than 7 days.